# tts not bound(Text to speech)

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement the text to speech found two packages on pub.dev but both of them got this error this cause crashing the app

on click button i call the function

```
FlutterTts flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    setList();
    _controller = ScrollController();
     flutterTts.setLanguage("en-US");
     flutterTts.setSpeechRate(0.7);
     flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
     flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
    super.initState();
  }
//calling this function on click 
  _speak() async {
    setState(() {
      flutterTts.speak(alp[index].SpekingAlphabets);
    });
  }
```

Error:

speak failed: not bound to TTS engine

Asked to disconnect from ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}